# Программное отключение телефона

Tags: java, android

Нужно как-то в android приложении сделать так, чтобы при вызове void'a отключался телефон (полностью, не экран). Как это сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых устройство должно быть рутованным, ну и команда:

```
void shotdown() throws IOException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot -p"});
}
```